# C - System(""); Execute one at a time

Tags: c, shell, ubuntu

I've got a system("sudo apt-get update | sudo apt-get -y install apache2 zip unzip"); etc, but its doing all the same commands at once?, how do i make it so it does one after the other is finished?, also some may ask the user to enter information from apt-get, how do i allow this to show?

Comment: What are the indications which make you think that both the commands are executed at the same time?

Comment: They are all in one system call, but apt-get seams to be saying its locked, though theres no process before that system call

Comment: is there any reason you are using C?

Comment: @ghostdog74 I'm going to be using a mixture of C and Shell Script, however it's going to contain somethings of which the user should not be able to get the source to (Commercial Program)

Comment: The commands you are trying to execute and the situation seems to me that you are building a terribly inadequate solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve. Why running interactive commands from application code? Why running system administration commands from application code? Why sudo? Why Debian-specific commands? Oh man... so many terrible assumptions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That pipe character (`|`) means that the output from `sudo apt-get update` is being piped into the input of `sudo apt-get -y install apache2 zip unzip`. Although this doesn't actually make any sense, it does mean both get launched at the same time, which is not what you want.

Either replace the single call with two individual system() calls:

```
system("sudo apt-get update");
system("sudo apt-get -y install apache2 zip unzip");
```

Note that when you call system(), your program doesn't resume until the process you launched has exited, so this means the first call will execute, then the second.

Or replace the pipe with `&&` (isn't necessarily guaranteed to work, though it really should on any Linux system):

```
system("sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install apache2 zip unzip");
```

Which means the right-hand side of the command will execute only if the left-hand side exits without error (technically, has an exit status of 0).

You can also replace the pipe with a semicolon (`;`) instead, which should execute both commands in sequence regardless of the exit status of the first command.